# What options do I have in terms of porting my XNA game to Mac?

Tags: macos, xna, mono

I've been reading a lot into this and MonoMac/Mono seemed to be the best if not one of the only ways to go about it. I do have a MacBook Pro and it seems Xamarin bought Mono and wants something like $800 for a business edition to be able to load in Visual Studio projects. I only downloaded the free version so when I tried to load in my VS project on my Mac into Xamarin it said it didn't recognize it and that's when I discovered it seemed I needed a business edition.

A lot of what my search found was stuff that was 1-2 years old and even older. Things seemed to have changed a bit since then and with the Xamarin integrating Mono sort of thing. I've been working on an XNA 4.0 game for PC for over 7 months now and I'd like to have a Mac version. Apparently games like Magicka have figured it out and were made in XNA. I plan to release on Steam so I suppose I need to find a way to try and make it work with Steam if that's possible too. I don't really use my MacBook that often and I don't have Steam on it so I'm not really sure how to go about this.

I guess it comes down to this. I don't understand the current situation of MonoMac and Xamarin and did they aquire Mono? Do I need that expensive business edition? Are there alternatives? How does this tie in to being able to release a Mac version on Steam?

Most of the information I can find is a few years ago now and a lot has changed it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**MonoGame**](http://www.monogame.net/) is a re-implementation of the XNA API for various platforms, including Mac.

It *depends* on **Mono** to provide a C# runtime across different platforms. And on platform specific versions of Mono (such as MonoMac, MonoTouch, etc, from Xamarin) to provide the API bindings and other features specific to those platforms.

You don't so much "load" an existing Visual Studio project as create a *new* project - either in Visual Studio (if the tools are available and you've bought them - but I don't think this is the case for Mac) or MonoDevelop or Xamarin studio.

To your new project, you would add your existing source files and add a reference to the MonoGame library for that platform. That MonoGame library will provide versions of the classes in the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` namespace that work on that platform. Your code gets compiled against these alternate classes, creating a new binary specific for that platform.

(MonoGame will probably have more in-depth documentation of the process on their website, including how to deal with game content.)

Put simply: Use MonoGame. It is an alternate version of the XNA library, not a conversion tool.

Comment: One additional question for you. I've got MonoDevelop up and going on my MacBookPro and no matter what I do I always get: "Build failed. Could not find a part of the path "/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Info.plist"." When I try to build a project.

Comment: No idea. Perhaps ask a new question and see if anyone else knows :)

Comment: You need to install Xcode to get the native compiler toolchain